# Jquery AutoComplete with database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the code for the autocomplete search bar.

The only thing I can think of is that I referenced the wrong thing under URL

aspx Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Admin_home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'Car':'" + document.getElementById('query').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    Error: function(results) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>`
```

aspx html code

I cant seem to type or paste the html here.  It is just a
asp:Textbox ID="query" class="ui.autocomplete"

c# code

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string Car)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CarsConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Car from T_Car where Car like '%'+ @SearchText +'%", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", Car);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["Car"].ToString());
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Would part of the html need to be wrapped in an AJAX update panel?

Also, I am having the search pull names from sql server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is not how jQuery Autocomplete works,

jQuery autocomplete automatically sends the text entered in the text box to the location you specify in a querystring "term"  you access it in webmethod or handler like this

```
         string input = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["term"];
```

something like this

```
              [WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string Car)
{
    string input = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["term"];
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CarsConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Car from T_Car where Car like '%'+ @SearchText +'%", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", input);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(dr["Car"].ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

this goes in your .aspx page

```
    $(".ui-autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: "Admin_home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
        select: function (event, ui) { }
      });
```

EDIT:

I've never actually done this in web method , I usually use a handler .ashx , but this should work  just as good.

when you have all that changed , then run the site in  debug mode, start to type in the textbox and fit f12 and watch the traffic that this is causing - if you type "abc" it should look like

Admin_home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData?term=abc

then the response you might have to play with a little , by default .net is going to add "d :  ...."   to the response to client side , but you can watch it and adjust accordinly

Another Edit:

```
         <asp:Textbox ID="query" class="ui.autocomplete">
```

is not what you put in the jquery

```
          $(".ui-autocomplete").autocomplete({
```

it should be

```
         <asp:Textbox ID="query" class="ui-autocomplete">
```

Yet, Another Edit:

This is missing a single quote

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Car from T_Car where Car like '%'+ @SearchText +'%", con))
```

replace with

```
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Car from T_Car where Car like '%'+ @SearchText +'%' ", con))
```

Comment: yes, I'll post your JAVASCRIPT as well, don't call it java - java guys will yell at you

Comment: So what would be in place for "term?"

Comment: leave that line alone, jquery automatically sends a querystring named "term"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thanks for your help.

However, it is erroring me with the "name 'context' does nto exist in the current context"

Comment: My Request.QueryString is just plain jane black.  Not baby blue

Also, what were you meaning with the asp:Textbox? I have the text box nested in a couple divs in the body. Are you saying that is wrong?

Comment: no, the only thing I was pointing out about the textbox is that you wrote class="ui.autocomplete"  , then in jquery you did ".ui-autocomplete"   one was a '-' and one a '.'

Comment: I nest the javascript you gave me under the function SearchText() { and remove the rest of the things that I had in there correct?

Also, with the source do I reference what page I am on? ie, if the code is going into Admin home.aspx then source would be Admin_home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData?

Comment: replace the entire jQuery with what I wrote , you can add to it what you want after you get it working - and the "source" is where the webmethod is located , it does not matter what page you are calling it from , you could use the same exact code from another aspx page and use  source: "Admin_home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData", for your source

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14539/discussion-between-user1512593-and-scott-selby)

Comment: google using jquery autocomplete with ashx  , the ashx handler is easier to user then a webmethod , but they both are very similar  and most of your code could be switched over to there

Comment: Yes. That is what I ended up doing. Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe it would help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Admin_home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{ 'Car': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                            return {
                                value: item
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
    </script>
```