# how to make the data show when i start typing

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

am working on a website using asp.net 
but am new to this 
i have information stored in database 
and then in the form i have the following 
**code   description    description (ar)**
these are colums of the table in the database 
i want the info in the database to show wheni start typing 
***for example*** if i write "a" all the words that start with a should show
how can i do that?

and what should i write here

```
 protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

??????

Comment: You should Make some search on AutocompleteBox.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680792/jquery-autocomplete-with-database

Comment: use ajax autocompleteextender

Answer (score 0):

1. Make event listener to your html text field, like
2. Do an ajax call to server method/action sending your input contents
3. Query database to get TOP(N) records, containing/starting with text you sent to server
4. Return strings/nothing to client side
5. If there are some results found show a tooltip, containing results

Answer (score 0):

you should use a ui framework for this purpose, see this example on [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/controlTypes.html)